# Floating-point issues in data compression using optimal predictors

Tags: java, c++, compression, geospatial

Does anyone have recommendations on ensuring the repeatability of floating-point operations across platforms for data compression using optimal predictors?

I have a Java implementation of data compression for terrestrial elevation and ocean depth information using the technique proposed by [Smith and Lewis, 1994](https://cartogis.org/docs/proceedings/archive/auto-carto-11/pdf/optimal-predictors-for-the-data-compression-of-digital-elevation-models-using-the-method-of-lagrange-multipliers.pdf). The technique uses Lagrange Multipliers to find the coefficients for a predictor function that can be integrated into a lossless data compression operation.  The results are pretty good.  For SRTM elevation data, I am seeing average rates of 1.9 bits per value (more or less depending on local terrain).   Implementation details are available at [Lossless Compression for Raster Data using Optimal Predictors](https://gwlucastrig.github.io/GridfourDocs/notes/CompressionUsingOptimalPredictors.html)

I am porting my code to C/C++, but I am concerned about numerical precision issues. The method absolutely depends on the ability to get the same results for floating-point calculations when the data is stored and when the data is recovered.  The key computation (there’s only one of them) is shown below (u and z variables are all IEEE-754 single-precision floats):

```
                float p
                = u1 * z1
                + (u2 * z2
                + (u3 * z3
                + (u4 * z4
                + (u5 * z5
                + (u6 * z6
                + (u7 * z7
                + (u8 * z8
                + (u9 * z9
                + (u10 * z10
                + (u11 * z11 + u12 * z12))))))))));
            int estimate = StrictMath.round(p); // this is the key result
```

The computation has a lot of extra parentheses because I wanted to avoid cases where a compiler might change associativity as part of its optimization.

I have run C-language tests processing millions of data points under Windows and Linux and, so far, I haven’t seen a single problem…  Of course, I’ve been working on similar hardware and the same compiler (gcc)  and  a few hundred million points don’t really prove anything.

Would it be sufficient to include a compiler directive such as

```
#pragma float_control(precise, on)
```

Are there particular environments out there that will be problematic? Also, I have the source code for Java’s StrictMath.round method (it works directly on bits). Do I need to implement an explicit C version or are there stock C/C++ functions I can rely on to work the same way?

Comment: C/C++ rounds ties _away from zero_, whereas Java rounds ties _up_. So for example, in Java, `StrictMath.round(-1.5)` gives `-1`, whereas in C `lround(-1.5)` gives `-2`.

Comment: "_I wanted to avoid cases where a compiler might change associativity as part of its optimization._": The C and C++ standards do not allow a compiler to do that and they don't by-default, although they typically have a compilation flag to enable "fast math" that is not conforming. Adding redundant parentheses wouldn't change anything either way. However, `+` is left-to-right associative in C and C++, so you are grouping them against their natural parsing direction.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. This is really useful information.  And, if you'll excuse me, it's kind of neat to get a comment related to data compression from Mark Adler himself.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this article: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/floating-point-determinism/

Comment: Thank you all three for your help. It led to some real progress on the C/C++ investigation. I am hoping that this discussion will help bring some more attention to data compression using the method of Lagrange multipliers for optimal predictors. It's really quite an elegant technique.